# Continuous functions and formal definition of the derivative - please check my reasoning

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If we have a function $f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{x = y} \\
0, & \text{$0$ otherwise}
\end{cases} $

To solve for the rate of change with respect to x, we get the following equation.

$\lim \limits_{h \to 0} f_x(x,y) = \frac{f(x + h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}$

Here's where I would like someone to check my understanding. We now have the following, which is correct.

$=$ $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(0+h, 0) - f(0,0)}{h}$

$= \frac{0 - 1}{h}$

$= -\infty$

Instead of the following, which is incorrect.

$=$ $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(0+0, 0) - f(0,0)}{0}$

This is due to the fact that $f(x,y)$ is **discontinuous** at $(0,0)$?

Although, we would usually proceed with **continuous** functions, such as polynomials, as follows.

$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^2 = 0$

Is this correct reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what your reasoning is.  You've shown that $f_x(0,0)$ doesn't exist as a real number.

Comment: @Bye_World I'm referring to my reasoning regarding the use of the formal definition of the derivative. This is my first time using the formal definition and I'm a bit rusty with limits. Specifically, I was confused for a moment with regards to whether the answer was $=$ $\lim \limits_{h \to 0}$ $\frac{f(0+0, 0) - f(0,0)}{0}$. I then realised that this was a mistake and came up with the other (correct) solution. However, I wanted to ensure that my reasoning is correct so that I can convince myself that I understand the concept.

Comment: It looks fine.  Obviously you wouldn't just plug in $h=0$ like in the line under "Instead of the following, which is incorrect." because that has no meaning ($0/0$ is undefined).

Comment: @Bye_World Yes, please see my updated response. So my reasoning is sound?

Comment: If your "reasoning" is that $$f_x(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h}$$ *if it exists*, then yes -- you are correct.

Comment: @Bye_World I'm referring to my reasoning as to why we get that answer, rather than the incorrect one. In other words, why we have $h$, rather than $h = 0$. See my lines on continuous and discontinuous functions.

Comment: Is this your question?: "Is $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0)-f(0,0)}{h} \ne \frac{f(0+0,0)-f(0,0)}{0}$ because $f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$?"  If so, the answer is partly.  $f$ not being continuous means $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h,0)\ne f(0,0)$, but there's also the issue of division by zero which has nothing to do with $f$ being continuous or not.

Comment: @Bye_World But we are using the formal definition of the derivative (and thus performing the limit operation) in this scenario, due to the fact that the function is discontinuous at $(0,0)$, right?

Comment: You're asking why you should use the definition of the derivative as opposed to the properties of the derivative to evaluate $f_x(0,0)$ in this case?

Comment: @Bye_World Yes. Kind of an extension to the question, 'under what conditions do we use limits?'.

Comment: Those properties that you know for the derivative all assume the derivative exists.  If you don't know, you have to use the definition.

Comment: @Bye_World Ok, thanks. Lastly, this function is discontinuous at $f(x,y) = (0,0)$, right?

Comment: Yes.  Why don't you try to prove it?

Comment: @Bye_World Yes, that comes next. :) Thank you very much.